# setInterval just wont stop with clearInterval

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I am trying to have a simple play and pause a photo slider but setInterval wont work for me can anyone see what I am doing wrong

I want it to stop when I click pause.

```
$('.control').click(function() {
    var data = $(this).attr('data-id');
    var interval;

    switch (data){
        case 'play':
            console.log('play');
            interval = setInterval(slide, 2000);
            break;
        case 'pause':
            console.log('pause');
            clearInterval(interval)
            break;
        default : console.log('nothing');
    }
```

Comment: What doesn't work and what is your expected outcome?

Comment: The `slide` function is not invoked?

Comment: I believe in javascript  you have to pass a string (that gets evaled) as your delayed method (rather than a reference to the actual method). So you would do setInterval("slide()", 2000);

Comment: @Dr.Dredel Nope. You don't. You can pass a reference. (That is also the preferred method.)

Comment: in that case either data never equals "play" or your slide method is not working correctly. You should post more code :)

Comment: -> [The code OP passed works](http://jsfiddle.net/Codemonkey/5QEh8/) <-

Comment: @NiftyDude I want it to stop using the slide function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `interval` variable is declared inside the function, and goes away when the function exits.  The next time the function is called, it has no value, so clearInterval is being passed `undefined`.  Declare `interval` outside the function and it should work.

Comment: Or better, store `interval` as a data attribute.

Comment: With no guard to ensure the "play" branch doesn't get hit twice before clearing the previous interval, it's still broken.

Comment: Thanks! That sorted it... I really should have worked that out myself! Thanks for your help! @spender sorted that out too thanks!

Comment: Thanks! This helped my finally resolve my issue. In my case, I had a stateless functional react component and was declaring the variable inside the component, so it was reset with every render. If you have a react functional component, don't forget to declare your interval variable before the component!